# Serialization and write object

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization

I wanted to know can we change the way serialization works in java , like say if we have two fields in a class and we create an object of the class. Can we change the order in which the fields of the object is serialized ? also is this any way related to writeObject() method that is used to write the data into a .ser file..?? please help

Thanks in advance....

I wanted to know how to do custom serialization..

Comment: Why? The order is immaterial.

Comment: if i want to control the what to be serialized and what not, it might help me..

Comment: It won't help you. The order that fields are serialized in is immaterial. They are deserialized by name, not by order.

Comment: Can i use out.write() for an Arraylist ?

Comment: No, but you can use `writeObject()` for any `Serializable` object.

Comment: how do serialize an array in externalization ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use Interface Externalizable. It will give you more control over your serialization and de-serialization process .

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Externalizable.html
[code example ] http://www.jusfortechies.com/java/core-java/externalization.php

from docs
Only the identity of the class of an Externalizable instance is written in the serialization stream and it is the responsibility of the class to save and restore the contents of its instances. The writeExternal and readExternal methods of the Externalizable interface are implemented by a class to give the class complete control over the format and contents of the stream for an object and its supertypes. These methods must explicitly coordinate with the supertype to save its state. These methods supersede customized implementations of writeObject and readObject methods.

Comment: Can i use out.write() for an Arraylist ?